# VB Browse Button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm just messing around with Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2010. Anyone know how I would make a "Browse for folder(or file)" button? I'm really new to VB and I'm just looking for some simple help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place a button on the form, handle the click event, and use the [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Using fld As New FolderBrowserDialog()
    If fld.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
      MessageBox.Show("Selected " & fld.SelectedPath)
    End If
  End Using
End Sub
```

For selecting a file, use the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) class:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles 
  Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
      MessageBox.Show("Selected " + ofd.FileName)
    End If
  End Using
End Sub
```